# Regex match character with negative lookbehind of two chars

Tags: regex, negative-lookbehind

I want to split a string using the character "/", but the split should only occur if there is no "\" in front of it.

String:

```
/10/102-\/ABC083.013/11/201201/20/83/30/463098194/32/7.7/40/0:20
```

Regex:

```
\/*(?<!\\)[^\/]*\/*(?<!\\)[^\/]*
```

Expected result:

```
/10/102-\/ABC083.013
/11/201201
/20/83
/30/463098194
/32/7.7
/40/0:20
```

But with my regex I get:

```
/10/102-\
/ABC083.013/11
/201201/20
/83/30
/463098194/32
/7.7/40
/0:20
```

[online regex example](https://regex101.com/r/xbkgQs/1)

The issue is on the first group "/10/102-\/ABC083.013", it does not recognize the string  "\/" to the first group. I don't know how to optimize/change my regex so that it recognizes the first group correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
(?:\/[^\\\/]+){2}(?:\\\/[^\\\/]+)?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3jBr2m/1). *Details*:

- `(?:\/[^\\\/]+){2}` - two occurrences of

  - `\/` - a `/` char
  - `[^\\\/]+` - one or more chars other than `/` and `\`
- `(?:\\\/[^\\\/]+)?` - an optional occurrence of:

  - `\\` - a `\` char
  - `\/` - a `/` char
  - `[^\\\/]+` - one or more chars other than `/` and `\`

Comment: That works perfectly. With {2} I had also tried but obviously wrong. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Maisen1886 `(?:\/[^\\\/]+){2}` is equal  to `\/[^\\\/]+\/[^\\\/]+`. Repetitions of pattern *sequences* should be defined with non-capturing groups (if supported), with `(?:...)`.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to match 2 times a forward slash, and only match a `/` when preceded by a `\`

```
(?:\/(?:[^\/]|(?<=\\)\/)+){2}
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\/` Match `/`
  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `[^\/]` Match any char other than `/`
    - `|` Or
    - `(?<=\\)\/` Match `/` not preceded by `\`
  - `)+` Close group and repeat 1+ times to match at least 1 char other than `/`
- `){2}` Close group and repeat 2 times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MdsggS/1)

---

Or a slightly more efficient unrolled version

```
(?:\/[^\\\/]+(?:\\.[^\\\/]*)*){2}
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\/[^\\\/]+` Match `/` followed by 1+ times any char other than `\` and `/`
  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `\\.[^\\\/]*` Match an escaped char followed by 0+ times any char other than `\` and `/`
  - `)*` Close the group and repeat 0+ times (in case there are no occurrences of an escaped char)
- `){2}` Close group and repeat 2 times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/w0YhfW/1)